# Get client environment information by cookies

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I just started with Java servlets few days ago. I am trying to develop a program just for practice and to get to know the the stuff we can do with Java servlets.

Trying to have a program that generates a cookie and sends it back to the client in response.
Sending back the cookie and getting cookie info back is fine, but what I want to do is that can we get information about the clients environment using cookies as well as can we get the browser information using cookies, such as which browser, its version, OS, etc.

I know they store state information since HTTP is stateless. So I was just wondering and trying is there a way to get client's environment information and browser information by cookies in servlets.

Comment: Your question is very broad. I would recommend a good HTML book or online tutorial.

Comment: If you want client info, then look at request headers. Try code at  http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are not designed to get client information. You have  to use `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` methods - `getHeader()` or `getHeaders()` method to read request header key-value.

```
 Enumeration names=request.getHeaderNames();

  while(names.hasMoreElements())
     {
     String key=names.nextElement().toString();
     String value=request.getHeader(key);
     }
```

Want to get value of `user-agent` key.

```
String userAgent=request.getHeader("user-agent");
```

Comment: Sorry for replying soo late! but thanks .. your post helped me! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class GetCookiesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<B>");
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            String name = cookies[i].getName();
            String value = cookies[i].getValue();
            pw.println("name = " + name + "; value = " + value);
        }
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Please visit this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/header-information-available.shtml)

Comment: Question is whether we retrieve client information (.which browser, its version, OS) via  cookies?

Comment: see this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/header-information-available.shtml)

Comment: i too refer that site many times :P , dost! thanks for the link! :)